# How to fill cells of JFreeChart with some background color

Tags: java, jfreechart, java-2d

Is there any way to fill cells of `JFreeChart` (`CategoryPlot`) with some background color? In the attached picture I show the desired result (red colored box).

Do I need to create `Java2d` graphics and put them on top of a chart? Or should I override some function?

[image]

Comment: Or XYBoxAnnotation if the cell isn't part of the dataset.

Comment: @trashgod: Is it possible to apply XYBlockRenderer on CategoryPlot?

Comment: @David Gilbert: I tried to use XYBoxAnnotation but it does not work on CategoryPlot